# Visual Studio Code JSON Setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows 10, and I ran into an error following an update on VS Code, and now my JSON settings are all messed up.

For some reason, even after uninstalling and deleting the .vscode folder, removing all traces I can find of Visual Studio Code, then reinstalling VS Code the JSON settings  are the exact same as they were when I uninstalled. There is no change, and I can't figure out how to "reset" them to the default/correct settings for my user profile.

I have no idea how to reset JSON to default, I don't understand why a complete uninstall/reinstall and removal of the .vscode folder I end up returning to the exact same JSON settings in VS Code.

It's gotten to the point where VS Code is completely unusable no matter what I do, and no matter what programming language I try to use.

Any insight or help is incredibly needed.

Comment: Before and after description of the json may help.

Comment: When you say "program language" is it a .json file or json in a file of a non json language?

Comment: It's the settings.json which launches when I select the launch.json option. Even though I have uninstalled/reinstalled Visual Studio code, and deleted all app data, the settings.json never actually return to their default. They remain what they were the last time I opened them, again, even though I have removed every trace I can find of VS Code. It doesn't make any sense that there is any remnant of VS Code on my machine.

Comment: Sounds impossible to cache somethg through all that so it feels like the json file might have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to "factory reset" VS Code on my computer and found this youtube video very helpful. This might solve your problem. In the video, he states the following:

1. Uninstall VS Code
2. Delete the ".VSCode" folder

This PC > Local Disk (C:) > Users > "Account Name" > .vscode

3. Delete the "Code" folder

This PC > Local Disk (C:) > Users > "Account Name" > App Data > Roaming > Code

4. Reinstall VS Code

Be sure to permanently delete the files by pressing shift+delete. As soon as the installation was complete, VS Code booted up like it was the first time. If his video helped you, please give the video creator a like. Link to the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR3yOvea6tY

Comment: Thanks, but VS Code is still doing the same thing. I don't what I am doing incorrectly, or how I am this incompetent, so I'm just going to find a different IDE. I can't learn any languages at this point in VS Code since I can't run anything.

Thanks for the sending a suggestion though.